# How to dynamically set auth in handshake in Socket.IO client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, socket.io

On the frontend/client-side, I have an implementation where I secure my socket.io connection using auth token. This auth token is updated in the store every few minutes.

```
const authToken = getToken()
socket = io(WS_BASE_URL, {
    auth: {
        token: authToken
    }
});
```

In this current implementation, when the socket tries to **reconnect**, `authToken` is not updated. How to dynamically set it every time `reconnect` attempt is made?

```
socket = io(WS_BASE_URL, {
    auth: {
        token: () => getToken()
    }
});
```

I want this kind of implementation where I pass a function to get the token every time from the store. Or is there any way we can modify handshake data in the `reconnect_attempt` event?

```
socket.io.on("reconnect_attempt", () => {
    // update handshake
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[socket.io 2.x client api](https://socket.io/docs/v2/client-api/#with-query-option) document has this

"The query content can also be updated on reconnection:"

```
socket.on('reconnect_attempt', () => {
  socket.io.opts.query = {
    token: 'fgh'
  }
});
```

I think you use 4.x because you use `auth` option, but I think it is basically the same. The middleware at server side will get the update token when a socket reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback option. You probably have found out the solution but just for future reference:

```js
const socket = io(
    "/path", 
    {
       auth: (cb) => cb(yourFunctionToGetToken()),
    }
);
```